# How to add platform-specific plugin to flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, apple-sign-in

I've add apple_sign_in plugin to my existing flutter projects. I see that this plugin only support iOS, thus now when I build the project for android I get the following error.

```
Plugin project :sign_in_apple not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/kardoaziz/Documents/flutter_projects/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 473
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object

inside the dart code I am checking the platform before using the plugin I get no error there. but in the build the following error appears.
I appreciate your time, please any solution ?